# Why am I receiving a NullPointerException in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am developing an Android application that uses a `GET` request to retrieve a list of filters in a `JSON` response. This part of the application had been working since first implementing it up until recently. I was working on other portions of the project when I noticed that starting the application and opening the activity that retrieves the filters stopped working and will produce an exception, despite the fact that this part of the project did not get touched with any direct code changes.

The activity I have that calls to the server and receives the filter list is `FindMeARestaurantActivity` and has an `AsyncTask` called `GetFiltersTask` that ensures this task is not executed in the UI layer. I use a `DAO` called `restaurantDAO` that makes the HttpURLConnection call. It is in this class that the exception is happening. When I debug and step into the `restaurantDAO.getFilters()`, the exception happens when I try to step over the `connection.connect()` line and receive this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator()' on a null object reference`. I have no clue why this is happening as I have not touched this code, the endpoint still sends the `JSON` response (tested in a browser), and I do not know where this `null` value is coming from. Here is my `AsyncTask` and the `getFilters()` method in the `DAO` respectively:

```
    public class GetFiltersTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<CheckboxDTO>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pbProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) {
            pbProgressBar.setProgress(integers[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<CheckboxDTO> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String serverResponse = restaurantDAO.getFilters();
            try
            {
                // Create JSON Object with contents of server response
                JSONObject jsonResponseObject = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
                // Grab the JSON Array of filters from the JSON Object
                JSONArray jsonResponseArray = jsonResponseObject.getJSONArray("filters");

                // For loop to iterate through each returned filter from server, generate a checkbox for them,
                // then append those to the linear layout
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponseArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    // Create CheckboxDTO object
                    CheckboxDTO checkboxDTO = new CheckboxDTO();
                    // Grab JSON Object out of JSON Array
                    JSONObject objects = jsonResponseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Grab the ID and Value from JSON Object
                    int id = objects.getInt("id");
                    String name = objects.getString("name");

                    // Assign JSON Object's key/value pair to CheckboxDTO's private fields
                    checkboxDTO.setId(id);
                    checkboxDTO.setValue(name);

                    // Add the CheckboxDTO to the checkboxes array
                    checkboxes.add(checkboxDTO);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return checkboxes;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<CheckboxDTO> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pbProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            makeCheckboxes(result);
        }
    }
```

And

```
@Override
    public String getFilters() {
        String inputLine;
        String result;
        try
        {
            // Create URL object to hold URL
            URL filterURL = new URL(filtersURL);
            // Create connection to server
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) filterURL.openConnection();

            // Set connection methods and timeouts
            connection.setRequestMethod(FILTERS_REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            // Connect to server
            connection.connect();

            // Create InputStreamReader to read response from server
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

            // Create BufferedReader to read through InputStream
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Check if the line being read is not null
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }

            // Close out InputStream and BufferedReader
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();

            // Set result to our inputLine with stringBuilder
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Error stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.chooseurfood, PID: 4108
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at java.net.CookieManager.get(CookieManager.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.networkRequest(HttpEngine.java:714)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:223)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
        at dao.FindMeARestaurantDAO.getFilters(FindMeARestaurantDAO.java:146)
        at com.chooseurfood.ui.FindMeARestaurantActivity$GetFiltersTask.doInBackground(FindMeARestaurantActivity.java:219)
        at com.chooseurfood.ui.FindMeARestaurantActivity$GetFiltersTask.doInBackground(FindMeARestaurantActivity.java:204)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Any help in getting this resolved would be appreciated.

Comment: post the complete exception stack trace

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I edited the post with my stacktrace from the debugger console. If it helps narrow things down, this apparently stops happening when I remove the `android:name=ClassThatExtendsApplication` from the Manifest file. The reason I used an extension of Application is because I was told this was how to use global variables and where to declare a CookieManager